# Simple 3 cells 12V lithium battery charger design and concept

Tags: lithium-ion, charge

[image]

I needed a simple 12V portable power supply for my high frequency inverter, and I have built one before, but yesterday, when I try to use it, the power is out. The batteries are low. SO I took it apart and start over. This time, I am going to use a regulated boost converter as my power input, a 10 Ohm resistor to limit the charging current because 1, the booster module that I am using can only switch 1A; 2, I don't use it this device a lot.

The above photo is my calculation and my questions are 1, are there any error; 2, any suggestions?

Comment: **FOR YOUR SAFETY** never charge a battery with anything other than a charger intended for batteries of the correct chemistry and voltage. **Property damage, injury, or death** may result if you don't.

Comment: A circuit like that could cause the battery to explode. Either get a proper lithium battery charger, or switch to a different (spelled s-a-f-e-r) battery technology.

Comment: BTW: the words "lithium battery charger" and "simple" should never be used in the same sentence.

Comment: Use a charger designed for the battery your charging. If possible monitor the battery temperature. Lithium batteries can catch on fire or explode. The raw Lithium metal may flash into flame if exposed to moist air. Do it the right way, the safe way, or find another hobby.

Comment: I don't follow your calculations. Actually, they make no sense. How did you calculate current using only voltages? 12.6V is the correct max voltage for 3 cells. It would be better to charge the cells individually. If their capacities vary slightly, one of the cells will be over-charged, and another will be under-charged when charged in series. Lithium batteries cannot be floated. You need to add circuitry that detects when the cells are full and disconnects the voltage supply from the battery. Read what off-the-shelf IC's do.

Comment: let's assume that the battery is in good condition. I don't think you can over-charged a 4.2v battery with only, say, 4.15v input.

Comment: But let's assume that one cell fails to stay in good condition. If it shorts, what voltage do the other two cells see? And how long will they see it before they burn or explode? At a minimum, a lithium charger should have a temperature monitor, because everything does not always work like it should.

Answer (score 1):

1. The maximum charging voltage for a 3.6V (nominal) Li-ion cell is normally 4.1V, but you say 4.2V is 100%. Most modern Li-ion cells are 3.7V. Either you have some unusual cells, or this is an error.
2. Your boost voltage is apparently regulated to 12.4V, but the battery needs 12.6V for a full charge. If this is intentional then not telling us why is a mistake.
3. In the diagram you show a 100Ω resistor, but in the text you say it is 10Ω. One of these values must be wrong, or there is something you aren't telling us (a mistake).
4. You subtract the cutoff voltage from the boost voltage to get 2.32V, then divide by 100 to get 23mA. So the resistor is 100Ω. But then you divide by 10 to get 232mA, so the resistor is now 10Ω?
5. "12.4V - 5V = 7.4V" doesn't seem to be relevant.
6. You assume 80% boost efficiency, but have no calculations or measurements to prove it. The actual efficiency could be much lower.
7. When charging, the battery voltage will rapidly rise towards 12.6V and current will go down accordingly, resulting in a very long charge time.

Here is an example of a Li-ion cell being charged. You can see that the voltage rises to 3.75V almost immediately, then ramps up to 4.2V at about 80% charge. With 12.4V through a resistor you won't get this curve though, because the battery will charge slower and slower as its voltage rises and the voltage across the resistor decreases.

[image]

Trying to charge a Li-ion battery through a current limiting resistor like this is a mistake. You should use a booster which has internal current limiting, or better yet a proper Li-ion charger.

Comment: 1, nominal voltage is 3.6/3.7v; full capacity voltage is 4.20v. It's also safe to charge it up to 4.35V to get more capacity out of battery, thought this will limit the lifespan. 4.1v is for better lifespan, not fully charged.

2, since it doesn't have cut-off circuit, getting the water bucket 100% full is dangerous, but it's totally safe to get to 95% full. that makes sense?

3-7, I did 2 calculations to figure out the ideal values for the resistor; and found out that 10 ohm is better in this case. The efficiency is not as important. what important is whether it works or not.

Comment: Yes, charging to 4.1V/cell can improve lifespan. However the resistor reduces charge current towards zero as the voltage approaches 4.1V, so it will never quite get there. Charging with 12.6V will be faster, and you could charge until the battery actually gets to 12.4V (at which point the the charge current would 20mA).

Answer (score 0):

I think the general idea of charging from a cautious voltage (3 x typical 3.7V Li-ion cells suggests 11.1V to me) via a cautious resistor (allowing maybe capacity ÷ 10, eg. 0.5A for a 5Ah battery) is fine. It can't overcharge because there's zero current when the battery reaches (matches) its nominal / happy voltage (as supplied); it can't heat up dangerously during charge because you pick the resistor to avoid this even if the battery is flat (11.1V ÷ 0.5A = 22.2 Ohms; 18 Ohms standard value should be fine).
•
Only problem I see is it'll be slow & probably won't reach 100% full but it beats chucking a good battery out just because the manufacturers on-board 'smart' chips are so dumb... (Or is that deliberate? £££)